# Nokia Qt: Save Image In Phone Memory

Tags: qt, symbian

I am making App. that includes Picture Editing, After Editing I want to save this Image As jpg file in my phone memory.. How can i do this?

Any help?

Thanks..

Comment: which platform are you developing against? meebo or symbian?

Comment: I am Developing against Qt for Symbian...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Symbian device to check, but AFAIK it should be something like e.g.

```
QString filename = "c:\\folder\\filename.jpg";
bool success = mypixmap.save(filename);
```

assuming you have Symbian capabilities to write to the directory.  The `success` will be true if the save was successful and false otherwise, and if necessary you can mess with the compression quality factor - [here's the documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpixmap.html#save).

I'm rusty on Symbian permissions, you might need WriteUserData to get this to work.